# How to invoke Expression<Func<Entity, bool>> against a collection

Tags: c#, linq, iqueryable, func

I have an interface that defines a repository from the Repository pattern:

```
interface IRepository
{
    List<Customer> GetAllCustomers(Expression<Func<Customer, bool>> expression);
}
```

I've implemented it against Entity Framework:

```
class EntityFrameworkRepository
{
    public List<Customer> GetAllCustomers(Expression<Func<Customer, bool>> expression)
    {
        return DBContext.Customers.Where(expression).ToList();
    }
}
```

That seems to work well, it allows me to do something like:

```
var customers = entityFrameworkRepository.Where(
    customer => String.IsNullOrEmpty(customer.PhoneNumber)
);
```

Now I'd like to have an InMemoryRepository for testing and demo purposes. I attempted to create one:

```
class InMemoryRepository
{
    Dictionary<int, Customer> Customers {get; set;} = new Dictionary<int, Customer>();

    public List<Customer> GetAllCustomers(Expression<Func<Customer, bool>> expression)
    {
        //what do I put here?
    }
}
```

As you can see in the above code, I'm stumped on what to do for `InMemoryRepository.GetAllCustomers` implementation. What should I do there to filter the Customers by the provided expression and return the results?

I tried:

```
return Customers.Where(expression));
```

But obviously it's expecting a `Func<KeyValuePair<int, Customer>, bool>` so I get a compilation error:

> Error CS1929  'Dictionary' does not contain a definition for 'Where' and the best extension method overload 'Queryable.Where(IQueryable, Expression>)' requires a receiver of type 'IQueryable' DataAccess.InMemory

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Try [.AsQueryable()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb507003(v=vs.110).aspx) method:

```
return Customers.Values.AsQueryable().Where(expression);
```

Comment: I spent like an hour on this, and you get me in less than a minute. Fantastic. A quick correction, it's `Customers.Values.AsQueryable().Where(expression);`

Comment: @mason yes, of couse. glad to help!

Comment: Why is this necessary? EntitySet already implements IQueryable, right?

Comment: @Protectorone because `Customers.Values` is not `EntitySet`

Answer (score -1):

Example

```
Expression<Func<Products, bool>> expresionFinal = p => p.Active;

if (mydate.HasValue)
{
    Expression<Func<Products, bool>> expresionDate = p => (EntityFunctions.TruncateTime(c.CreatedDate) <= mydate);
    expresionFinal = PredicateBuilder.And(expresionFinal, expresionDate );
}

IQueryable<T> query = dbSet;


    query = query.Where(expresionFinal);
```

Comment: Not sure what you're going for here? The expression is already set, I can't change the form.

Comment: You need a Generic repository like this :

`public class GenericRepository<T> : IGenericRepository<T> , IDisposable where T : class
    {internal DbContext context;
        internal DbSet<T> dbSet;

public GenericRepository(DbContext context)
        {
            this.context = context;
            this.dbSet = context.Set<T>();
        }

public virtual IEnumerable<T> Get(Expression<Func<T, bool>> filter = null)
        {
            IQueryable<T> query = dbSet;
                query = query.Where(filter);
                return query.ToList();
        }
}`