# Repository pattern with list as its core in C#

Tags: c#

I'm following this site: http://deviq.com/repository-pattern/

Which has an example of a repository pattern using a DB context. I'm trying to implement this generic Repository class with a list (I want the Repository class. That's a requirement of mine). However, I'm having issues with the Find method.

```
public class Repository<T> : IRepository<T> where T : class
{
   private List<T> context;

   virtual public T Find(int id)
   {
      // I can't figure out a way to make this work with the list of a generic type
   }
}
```

Is this even possible to make a predicate in the List.Find() with just an ID parameter? I'm guessing no, but what are options?

Comment: context in a Repository Pattern is a DBContext object. It's not clear what you want to do.

Comment: I think you would need `T: IEntity` where `IEntity` has an id. Or you could use reflection to extract the `ID`.

Comment: Not entirely sure I understand the question. But if T implements an interface with property Id, then you could do Find(p => p.Id == id)

Comment: Presumably you'd need to know what `T` is.  Since it can be anything, there isn't much you can do here.  You could constrict `T` to a more specific type than just `class`, you could leave the method `abstract` and derived repositories can implement it, or you could omit `Find()` altogether and consuming code can add their own filter clauses.

Comment: @ataravati: In this case the "data store" is an in-memory collection.  The OP is simply building a repository around that data store.

Comment: Can you do reflection on T to pull out the ID field by string name perhaps? Clearly it would break if the actual class used doesn't have it but I'm fine with that.

Comment: @user441521: You *can*, though doing something like that is more often than not an indication of a design problem.

Comment: I think that is the only way if you don't want to use interfaces.

Comment: Repository Pattern makes sense if you have multiple datasets. If you only have one List as data source, why do you even need to create a Repository Pattern?

Comment: You either need to use interfaces, or make the repository non-generic, like the repository in my question [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32753012/how-to-invoke-expressionfuncentity-bool-against-a-collection).

Comment: I do have multiple datasets. This is used as a child class to specific implementations of those datasets, but I want this core foundation.

Comment: @ataravati: There could be multiple repositories, each with their own list.  Analogous to repositories built around database tables.  This is very commonly seen, for example, when building an in-memory test fake for a data layer.

Comment: This is what I'm doing Dave, but why make multiple repo's with their own list when they all could just be children of this Repository and take advantage of only having to derive it. Only  having the list defined once. Just looking for ways to do that.

Comment: @user441521: If everything in the domain meets a single interface then sure, you can create a single generic repository around that interface.  But if your models are distinctly different and don't share enough commonalities to build a repository, then they should have their own repositories.  (Basically, that "single interface" which defines your entire domain should be how you restrict `T` in this class.  If you don't have that, you can't do it.  At least not cleanly.)

Comment: They do all meet the same interface. They all have an ID field to them. I think the 2 answers below are good ideas. Just have to pick one to go with.

Comment: @user441521: In that case the `IEntity` answer is likely the simplest initial approach.  As a general word of advice, keep in mind that this sort of de-duplication is a worthy goal, but shouldn't come at the cost of brittle and complicated code.  It you have a single `IEntity` (or however you name it) interface in your domain, great.  If you end up using reflection, then you're likely not gaining enough from the de-duplication to justify the design.

Comment: This is terrible code. Do not use this pattern it is a failed pattern. You should not be implementing a generic repository in your application. Only a library should implement a generic repository, a library like... Entity Framework. See my longer answer on http://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/63933/is-this-repository-design-pattern-valid-and-efficient/63983#63983

Comment: @ChrisMarisic I'm starting to suspect you were attacked by a repository pattern when you were young. You really have deep hatred towards it.

Comment: @Chris, I do use entity framework as well, but I structure my code where I have a DataLayer project where I bring in entity framework and wrap it in my repository that has these generic functions (Find, Insert, Save, etc). Then I use that DLL in a Service layer that works on the repositoroies. Then the actual application that uses that Service DLL. I put this layer on top to avoid having EF code (which is DB implementation specific) in my service layer. my service layer provides the business logic queries but I don't want it to have EF stuff in it.

Comment: @user441521 i didn't say don't use repositories, i said don't use **generic**. Your repositories should have methods like `GetCustomersInvoices` `UpdateSalesRecords`. Also you should *never* have EF any where except inside your repositories. Your middle/business tiers should never have access to the connection and IQueryable, and your business layer should not be attempting to build any type of query information. Just provide the repository the parameters it needs (customerId, search text, etc)

Comment: I don't use my repositories for that. I place that stuff in the Service (business logic) layer (DLL) as those are now business logic things that I may want to use in many other projects. That along with more complex queries that the Service may need to implement. To me the Service Layer operates on the Data Layer. The Data Layer handles the physical connected to the DB and has generic implementations to manipulate it. The service layer then puts more complex logic on top of that for that specific service functionality.

Comment: I make these distinctions because often I need the Data layer of 2 or more projects put into their own service and I may not be updating sales records for my final new service so why would I want that function in my data layer? I want my data layer to just be a generic interface to the data I need for said service.

Comment: @TopinFrassi i do have a deep hatred of it. Literally entire months of my life are gone and wasted from writing brittle worthless code because people espoused the generic repository as "good"

Comment: @user441521 you should not be sharing data layers between solutions. your reusable generic repository is EF/Dapper.

Comment: @user441521 Chris is right. The generic repository pattern is more of an anti-pattern. Don't abstract over entity framework just for the trip of it. You'll regret it

Comment: @ChrisMarisic The thing is, being aggressive here on SE won't make people want to follow your idea. Change your attitude if you want to be listened.

Comment: Why would I not share data layers between solutions? You should only NOT do that when you are putting your business logic into them. Since I DON'T do that, my data layers because generic ways to get at various pieces of like data. However, I can make many services that often need to get at a lot of different data. That's why the service layer exists. I work in analytics where we pull together tons of different data sets to run logic on. This pattern has made it much easier and more organized on our end. This is what reusability is about.

Comment: @user441521  unless a project is an alternative and replacement to EF/Dapper there is absolutely no good design  that shares this across an app domain boundary. The correct way to share information across app domains are through a service endpoints or through a message bus / message queue.

Comment: My service layer is where the endpoints are created for the main app to use. The data layer is shared between the services. We never want raw data going over an endpoint. That's just silly for us. The only thing we want people using is data that's gone through our service layer to give them the final result. So us sharing the data layer between services is so we aren't recreating/dublicating EF stuff in our service layer. We don't think EF stuff belongs in the service/business logic layer and the business logic is often done via linq queries.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Another option, if you can't control the type of T so as to apply an interface, is to force your implementers to do the hard work.

```
public abstract class Repository<T> : IRepository<T> where T : class
{
   private List<T> context;

   public virtual public T Find(int id)
   {
       return context.FirstOrDefault(x => GetId(x) == id);
   }
   public abstract int GetId(T entity);
}
```

an example implementation may be

```
// entity
public class Stooge
{
   public Stooges MoronInQuestion {get;set;}
   public double MoeEnragementFactor {get;set;}
   public void PloinkEyes() { /*snip*/ }
   public void Slap() { /*snip*/ }
   public void Punch() { /*snip*/ }
   // etc
}

// enum for an Id? It's not that crazy, sometimes
public enum Stooges
{
    Moe = 1,
    Larry = 2,
    Curly = 3,
    Shemp = 4,
    Joe = 5,
    /* nobody likes Joe DeRita */
    //CurlyJoe = -1, 
}

// implementation
public class StoogeRepository : IRepository<Stooge>
{
    public override int GetId(Stooge entity)
    {
        if(entity == null)
            throw new WOOWOOWOOException();
        return (int)entity.MoronInQuestion;
    }
}
```

Comment: @user441521 This pattern can be seen in the KeyedCollection https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms132438(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: @Will WOOWOOWOOException. LOL

Answer (score 5):

You can declare that T has an Id property with something like this:

```
public interface IEntity
{
    int Id { get; }
}

public class Repository<T> : IRepository<T> where T : class, IEntity
{
    private List<T> context;

    virtual public T Find(int id)
    {
        return context.SingleOrDefault(p => p.Id == id);
    }
}
```

Comment: Interesting. So with this I assume I'd need T to implement the IEntity as well right?

Comment: Yes, you need a common interface. Unfortunately we don't have duck typing in C#